# Suggestion with Java(Line Jump)

Tags: java

I need some help with my java project. What I want to do is to let the user put in a number and  my program will then print that number starter from 1. I have also added field width to 5. What I want to do now is to make line jumps: For example the first line will have 1 character, the next will have 2, then next will have 3 and so on. The field width from the start will also increase on every line. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printNumbersB(0);
    }

    public static void printNumbersB(int x){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please put in: ");
        x = input.nextInt();

        for(int y = 1; y <= x; y++){



            System.out.printf("%5d", y);


            input.close();

        }

    }
}
```

How output should be:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIQND.jpg

Comment: try `System.out.printf("\n%5d", y);` or use `println` instead of `printf`

Comment: That doesnt help. That just puts everthing under eachother...

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: @user2819522, so it is not clear what you want in this case

Comment: Output:
1
 2 3
  4 5 6
   7 8 9 10
   11 12 13 14
And so on.

Comment: http://imgur.com/2QLTRlA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what you want to do. But from what I understand this is what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printNumbersB();
}

public static void printNumbersB(){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please put in: ");
    x = input.nextInt();
    //Should use String Builder
    String accumlationString = "";
    for(int y = 1; y <= x; y++){

        System.out.printf(accumulationString + "%5d",  y);
     accumulationString = accumulationString + "%5d";
;

        input.close();

    }

}
}
```

FINAL EDIT:
This works but their is a more efficient way to do this:

```
public static void printNumbersB() {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please put in: ");
int x = input.nextInt();
input.close();
//Should use String builder
String tab = "";
int lineNumber;
int num = 1;
breakfor:
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    System.out.println();
    lineNumber = i;
    tab = tab + " ";
    for (int j = lineNumber; j > 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(tab + num);
        num = num + 1;
        if(num > x)
            break breakfor;
    }

}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printNumbersB();
}
```

Comment: @alfasin Fixed it. The bottom code snipbit should work, I went a bit to quickly. Consider taking down-vote away.

Comment: Downvote removed. I didn't upvote because I don't like the use of labels, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int n = 45;
int counter = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < counter + i; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%" + counter + "d", j);
    }
    i += counter - 1;
    System.out.println();
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: You can initialize/increment both `counter` and `i` on the same line:
`for (int i = 1, counter = 1; i < n; i++, counter++) {`